# How to extract value from javax.naming.directory.Attribute

Tags: java, ldap, jndi

The question says everything. When I am printing an Attribute it is:

```
cn: WF-008-DAM-PS
```

The code snippet is:

```
private void searchGroup() throws NamingException {
    NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> searchResults = getLdapDirContext().search(groupDN, "(objectclass=groupOfUniqueNames)", getSearchControls());
    String searchGroupCn = getCNForBrand(m_binder.getLocal("brandId"), m_binder.getLocal("brandName"));
    Log.info(searchGroupCn);
    while (searchResults.hasMore()) {
        SearchResult searchResult = searchResults.next();
        Attributes attributes = searchResult.getAttributes();
        Attribute groupCn = attributes.get("cn");
        if(groupCn != null) {
            Log.info(groupCn.toString());               
        }
    }
}
```

How can I only get the value that is: `WF-008-DAM-PS`, that is without the key portion?
Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Invoke the `getValue()` method or the `getValue(int)` method.

Comment: Is these two methods are present in javax.naming.directory.BasicAttribute or javax.naming.directory.Attribute? There is a method get(int).

Comment: `Attribute` is an interface, `BasicAttribute` implements `Attribute`. So, `final Object o = groupCn.getValue()`, assuming `groupCn` is single-valued. If it is multi-valued, use the integer index as the parameter to `groupCn.getValue(index)`

Comment: Thanks but there is not such method getValue() neither in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/naming/directory/BasicAttribute.html or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/naming/directory/Attribute.html

Comment: You are using 1.4.2? You should upgrade as soon as possible. Check out [1.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/). Or better still, use the UnboundID LDAP SDK instead of JNDI - JNDI should not be used for new code.

Comment: Thank you for the reference of this SDK

Comment: @TapasBose Terry is for once mistaken. The methods are called get(), not getValue(), and this isn't something that changed after 1.4.2.

Answer (score 8):

The solution is:

```
Attribute groupCn = attributes.get("cn");
String value = groupCn.get();
```

Answer (score 2):

**General**

Let's say that we have:

```
Attributes attributes;
Attribute a = attributes.get("something");
```

- `if(a.size() == 1)`

  - then you can use `a.get()` or `a.get(0)` to get the unique value
- `if(a.size() > 1)`

  - iterate through all the values:

    ```
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < a.size() ; i++ ) {
        Object currentVal = a.get(i);
        // do something with currentVal
    }
    ```

    If you use `a.get()` here, it will return only the first value, because its internal implementation (in `BasicAttribute`) looks like this:

    ```
    public Object get() throws NamingException {
        if (values.size() == 0) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Attribute " + getID() + " has no value");
        } else {
            return values.elementAt(0);
        }
    }
    ```

Both methods (`get(int)` and `get()`) throws a `NamingException`.

**Practical example** 

(when the `Attribute` instance has multiple values)

```
LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);

Attributes attributes = ctx.getAttributes("", new String[] { "supportedSASLMechanisms" });
System.out.println(attributes); // {supportedsaslmechanisms=supportedSASLMechanisms: GSSAPI, EXTERNAL, DIGEST-MD5}

Attribute a = atts.get("supportedsaslmechanisms");
System.out.println(a); // supportedSASLMechanisms: GSSAPI, EXTERNAL, DIGEST-MD5

System.out.println(a.get()); // GSSAPI

for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    System.out.print(a.get(i) + " "); // GSSAPI EXTERNAL DIGEST-MD5
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter, please add an explanation about your decision ... I think that this is a very good answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:(checking attribute present or not before fetching attribute value)

```
            Attributes attributes = searchResult.getAttributes();
            Attribute mail = attributes.get("mail");
            if (mail != null)
               {
                   System.out.println(" Mail-id value from LDAP :"+mail.get());
               }
```